# Animate storyboard without triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a way to animate a storyboard without any triggers?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Blink" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Image x:Name="Blink" Source="{}pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/image.png" Opacity="0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually there is some sort of an event which is suitable to drive starting a storyboard.
For example the load event or when a binding value changes.

You can, however, target and start a storyboard in code.

You use the Begin() method to start one running and you can either set the target on the storyboard or pass in the frameworkelement as a parameter.
Hence, if I have:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Storyboard x:Key="blinkingStoryboard">
       <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1" />
       </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Name="redRectangle" Opacity="0"/>
```

I can make the red rectangle blink by grabbing that storyboard out of resources and calling begin with a parameter of the rectangle:

```
        Storyboard sb = this.Resources["blinkingStoryboard"] as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin(this.redRectangle);
```